# Access the json response from xhr in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, xmlhttprequest

I have a question about how the `XMLHttpRequest` object works. In https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest, under properties I am looking at the "response" property. The description says I should get a JavaScript object back if my content type is json. However, in my code the `xhr.response` property is `undefined`.

Specifically, I have a `.ajaxSuccess()` callback that is setup on a DOM element, it receives the parameters `(event, xhr, settings)`.  `xhr.responseText` is the plaintext version of my json, but xhr.response is undefined. Is there any way I can get the object from xhr without calling `$.parseJson(xhr.responseText)`?

Comment: check if server returns "application/json" content-type. This can be the reason for jquery to not automatically parse json.

Comment: hmm, yes my xhr.responseType is undefined too. But in my server code (web.py framework) I do call web.header("Content-Type", "application/json"). Can you think of any reason the xhr isn't getting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the `XMLHttpRequest` object with jQuery's `jqXHR` object used by `$.ajaxSuccess()`, which is *supposed* to be a superset of the former.

Instead, you could use `$.ajax()`'s `done` handler, which will parse the JSON for you *if* the data type is `json`. For example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
}).done(function (response) {
  // response is a JSON object, previously parsed by jQuery using $.parseJSON
});
```

Also note that even though the documentation of [`$.ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) says that you get a vanilla `XMLHttpRequest` object, **that is no longer true** as of jQuery **1.4.1**. Instead, you [get](http://jsfiddle.net/9FD39/1/) a `jqXHR` object.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But I am not using a local callback, I am using the .ajaxSuccess() global callback, which according to this doc http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/, you get a vanilla XMLHttpRequest object

Comment: @afwu: But it's not, at least if you are using jQuery > 1.4.1. Check this fiddle, and see the result of `xhr instanceof XMLHttpRequest`. http://jsfiddle.net/9FD39/

Comment: Thank you Joao, I stand corrected. So I guess if its jqXHR is there a property of the jqXHR that is a javascript object of my json? And how did you know it was different for versions > 1.7? thanks

Comment: @afwu: I'm afraid not. You have to parse `jqXHR.responseText` using `$.parseJSON`, which is what jQuery is doing behind the scenes, to pass the parsed data to the `$.ajax` callback as you can see from its source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L319. Unfortunately, the same is not done for the global `$.ajaxSuccess` handler. This is meant to act as a *global* handler, maybe used in conjunction with `$.ajaxStart` to show a modal loading window, and hiding it on success. Maybe that's the reason why jQuery doesn't parse the object for you in this situation.